# Rails & Google Maps not showing markers

Tags: google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using GMapsForRails Gem (https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails), but my markers aren't being shown. I was figuring out if somebody could help me with it.

This is my index.html view:

```
div style=("width: 100%; height: 100%")
  #map_spaces style=("width: 90%; height: 400px;")

= javascript_include_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"
= javascript_include_tag "http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"

- content_for :scripts do
  javascript:
    var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map_spaces'}}, function(){

      if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(centerMap);
      } else {
        handler.map.centerOn(new google.maps.LatLng(-10.1885145,-48.3317027));
      }
      addMarkers(#{raw @spaces.to_json});
    });



    function centerMap(position){
      handler.map.centerOn(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    };

    function addMarkers(markers){
      handler.addMarkers(markers);
    };
```

These are my gems on Gemfile

```
# Geodecoder + gmaps location services
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

This is my spaces_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @spaces = Space.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
       marker.lat space.latitude
      marker.lng space.longitude
    end
  end
```

And this is my generated HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>EspacoStartup</title><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-3d13c2c09ad4b2aef84c3abcd9e6354e.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" /><meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="MkFjFwzYalVPWYubEFrdhagjdkWyvLhaQwDLub76bCuEUmBbBFC1WhSXaTMTy/T5evU6zHHcnYcAZzYYIcPz2Q==" /><!--[if lt IE 9]><![endif]--><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <!--XRAY START 147 /Users/sergio/Sources/ruby/espaco-startup/app/views/general/index.html.slim-->
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <div id="map_spaces" style="width: 90%; height: 400px;"></div>
      </div>
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;amp;sensor=false&amp;amp;libraries=geometry"></script><script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
      <!--XRAY END 147-->
    </div>
  </head>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/xray-651341ed77338019389130ebd5ec62ec.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs-e27bd20a10d28155845a22d71ef94f2f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix-31984abe1036c1c2f684af192191ce9f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert-7c03e11fecf6b3ef100f76ae4f08586e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/button-98bba85be4dcdd597554e0b7ce8e33a2.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel-93f34f850a932957c93b7605c79faf45.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse-7a82a3d4fb154ded3d2702465e21ca00.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown-65c3929585250221f53bae696936ed44.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab-a90a1841af8c1eae12bfa5283a8093b0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition-9e4de96204f41141474e9dbb59570af9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy-e550695030be1d627d1ba91b14792316.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal-ce380b9327d2cf6c826d8df818ea48a1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip-4d90d4ee015d2df34a7696864b2ea83c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover-5a060f876311e7fcb18f35058070de5a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets-00b1738c651720f44abc4bbf70bedb3e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/turbolinks-f87b3583ca50adb0488b031297f5580d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/underscore/underscore-min-d896593a6eaf631f476bf3407c295f6e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/base-123dd305868fd1a61725551efeba068e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/base/base-dca563082e65c8b42ab83b418286714b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/objects/base_builder-32c3edd5bf9b7fee1fb65c9a292432ed.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/objects/builder-3a2d17758d4383c26c7c11552b91900d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/objects/handler-62a5722bc03f7e1805af55255244cb5c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/objects/null_clusterer-184ef159404bbc224e9c51150c4efa63.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/common-247de1048a365563e2df3d5d5ae9e56c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/builders/bound-57d3060c7fe3ce4d42931e8abf50b9dc.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/builders/circle-99da4ddcaddd05a8c1097a06eeeefb90.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/builders/clusterer-6d81d0eb27c8c4e24380b2aacddc8511.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/builders/kml-6e2f09d2a688b881881a5f4357796aae.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/builders/map-325aa8626b5a5fa44312722237e15305.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/builders/marker-7432667e64b338c2c2895f4b4bd6349d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/builders/polygon-691f759a007e4be8af9d091666d09699.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/builders/polyline-796ac5f6a3a13881730d0c4d5d10644b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/bound-8b2391b8eaddc8625a459f0ce89c5c06.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/circle-abf49c4f2045e915f44fb1e5c99e5af7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/clusterer-2f010c47b83a2b1b084e393161211ede.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/kml-d4d5c668f5c4f7980f33620de06e4360.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/map-8462fffee7e2f45f07d15346aeedfa59.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/marker-55c756f18e3d1226031094349eb102ec.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/polygon-e9b75c55c73813811a991fd83c931218.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/objects/polyline-bd1d1f394197fdf7782eba9cdbae373b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google/primitives-f49c8e12ce8f7b5e295e8f04c590a4ce.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/gmaps/google-a30741f757343b7174ebd9c5710c9591.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application-d6f13875b2255f4a263042d4bd198da7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map_spaces'}}, function(){

      if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(centerMap);
      } else {
        handler.map.centerOn(new google.maps.LatLng(-10.1885145,-48.3317027));
      }
      addMarkers([{"id":1,"name":"test","description":"test space","created_at":"2015-03-01T12:02:21.746-03:00","updated_at":"2015-03-01T12:02:21.746-03:00","user_id":null,"address":"palmas tocantins","latitude":-10.249091,"longitude":-48.32428580000001}]);
    });



    function centerMap(position){
      handler.map.centerOn(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    };

    function addMarkers(markers){
      handler.addMarkers(markers);
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

And this is my HTML view without markers.
[image]
Does anybody had this kind of problem?

Comment: Just wondering, have you tried adding markers using the [**example**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) provided by google docs? Maybe you want to follow the basic example first and then add on to it.

Comment: I've made this. The problem was that I were using spaces hash instead of hash hash. Thanks. :)